# Electric guitar is too low without a strap

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, posture

I have been playing only acoustic guitar, until very recently I bought an electric (Ibanez RG350). I am finding it too low too play while practicing. With an acoustic I used to sit around and keep the guitar in my lap and play. But doing the same with the electric, I find it difficult to play as the guitar body is small compared to acoustic and it is very low.

What be a good posture to play an electric while sitting in a chair or a bed without having to bend forward?

Comment: Then why not use a strap while you are seated?

Comment: I want to avoid using a strap at all times, atleast not during daily practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electric guitars tend to be ergonomically engineered to be more comfortable hanging from a strap while standing. Electric guitar designers assume their guitars will be played standing, so the shape of the body tends to be more conducive to playing while standing.  Electric guitars also tend to be very heavy compared to acoustic guitars.

With an electric guitar, even if you play seated, you should use a strap to support the weight. If you try to play many electric guitars seated without a strap, between the weight, and the contours of the body, you will end up putting unintended and unnecessary stress on the muscles in your hands and arms just trying to keep the guitar from sliding out of your lap. And as you have observed, the smaller body puts the strings and neck in a lower position.  Plus, if most of the weight of the guitar is suspended from a strap, you will automatically sit in a more back friendly upright position as opposed to slouching over trying to reach the strings.

And speaking of straps. If you do plan to spend a good deal of time playing or practicing using a guitar strap, please consider getting a very comfortable strap. I like to use a very wide soft leather strap. The wide strap tends to spread out the pressure point on your shoulder over a wider area thereby increasing comfort. The soft leather tends to grip my shoulder better and I am not constantly trying to keep it from slipping.

Also, if you play for a long time with a strap, you will find it helpful to shift the position of the strap on your shoulder from time to time. You can slightly move it towards the end of your shoulder after awhile (and then back), to change the pressure point.

Be sure to adjust the strap for a comfortable playing position. You want the guitar to hang from your shoulder as close to playing position as you can get it. That's one reason why all guitar straps are adjustable.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the classical guitar posture, which requires a footstool. But it would only work if your electric guitar is of the correct body shape to sit well on your knee.

[image]

However, you should consider using a strap with your electric guitar, even when seated. The strap is there to enable you to position your guitar at the correct height and angle in order to play without bending over or assuming a bad posture. Using the strap could relieve you of fatigue.